# Set up protractor's conf file to use a custom reporter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, mocha.js, protractor

I'm currently setting up e2e tests with protractor.js, but the reporter uses dark words, and meshes horribly with my terminal window. [image]

How do I set up custom reporters so this doesn't look horrible?

Here's my entire protractor.conf.js

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  // Do not start a Selenium Standalone sever - only run this using chrome.
  chromeOnly: true,
  chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',

  // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4000/wd/hub',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['spec/e2e/*.js'],

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000',

  framework: 'mocha',

  reporters: ['mocha']

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how to change the style of reporter that mocha is using:

```
mochaOpts: {
  reporter: "spec",
  args: 
  slow: 3000
}
```

I also found out that the color issue is not just a matter of changing the reporter, but fixing a theming issue for my terminal window. Currently I'm using the Solarized Dark theme, and this is a problem for everybody that's using Solarized Dark.

https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/802
https://github.com/altercation/solarized/issues/220#issuecomment-17191676